# Where does "to" go in this sentence?

Tags: verbs, american-english, word-order

I'm writing a description on my resume. Which sentence is correct, or more correct?

1. > Licensed Master Social Worker assisting low-income, diverse students access higher education.
2. > Licensed Master Social Worker assisting low-income, diverse students *to* access higher education.
3. > Licensed Master Social Worker assisting low-income, diverse students access *to*  higher education.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about "Licensed Master Social Worker providing assistance to low-income, diverse students in accessing higher education."

Comment: Thank you. I like this and will use it. I am still curious which sentence is correct from my provided examples. My girlfriend and I were having a debate.

Comment: Honestly, I didn't like any of them.  Grammatically, probably the second is the most correct, IMHO.